# Limit to infinity of a function involving only gamma functions

Tags: limits, gamma-function

I'd like to compute the limit of

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to +\infty } \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {1 + \frac{x}{2}} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}}$$

Because of the physical problem involved, I can assume that x is even, i.e. x=2n (n positive non null integer) but... does it make sense to "approach infinity on even numbers"? Or this apparently oscillating function between +inf and –inf can somehow balance to zero? 
I’m little bit confused... 
Thanks in advance for any you can provide.
Regards

Comment: It certainly makes sense to ask for $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\Gamma((1/2)-n)\Gamma(1+n)\over\Gamma((1/2)+n)\Gamma(n)}$$ Whether it exists, or what it comes to, I don't know. What do you mean by "Oscillating between $\infty$ and $-\infty$"?

Comment: I just tried a plot, it goes to +-infinity on odd numbers (1, 3 ...) passing the 0 on even numbers (0, 2...). Not sure it helps, maybe it's misleading me to believe that the limit is not indeterminate while it actually is... Any idea? Is there a way to split limits on integer between odd and even numbers? or to relate the limit to some series representation? Thanks

Comment: You say in the body of the question that you can assume $x$ is an even integer. So let $x=2n$, and you get the expression I gave in my comment. As long as the limit is understood as the limit of a sequence ($n\to\infty$ through the integers) and not as the limit of a function ($n\to\infty$ through the reals), there is no difficulty here, and there's nothing wrong with saying the limit is zero.

Comment: Yep, but at least to reduce my question to prove that on odd numbers the +-inf balance to zero would simplify my physic result: or is it going as, say $(-1)^n$, and there's no hope? I start thinking to give up the search of the limit on reals :-/ Thanks

Comment: I don't know what "balance to zero" means. If you have the sequence $1,0,-2,0,3,0,-4,0,5,\dots$ then your sequence doesn't converge, but the subsequence $0,0,0,0,\dots$ of even terms converges to zero, and that's about all you can do. What I really don't understand is why you worry about the odd terms and the reals when you say you can assume $x$ is a positive even integer.

Comment: Well... going little bit beyond the mathematical formulation of the problem: this term is proportional to some physic quantities, to x=2n it correspond a kind of symmetry to the physics sys while the physic is different on x=2n+1 (the temr "is" apparently null or not). So the question arises spontaneously: what happen to my physical system if I have n=10^5 or n=1+10^5 or infinite? Unfortunately, I don't find (Gradshteyn&Ryzhik? and Abramowitz&Stegun?) simple expansion of Gamma function for arguments very big nor Google seems to help... Thank you in advance for the help, regards, Ste

Comment: For large positive $n$, $\Gamma(n)$ is very well-approximated by Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of the Gamma function yield
$$
{\frac {\Gamma \left( 1/2-x/2 \right) \Gamma \left( 1+x/2 \right) }{
\Gamma \left( 1/2+x/2 \right) \Gamma \left( x/2 \right) }}={
\frac {\pi\,x}{2\sin \left(\pi\, \left( 1+x \right)/2  \right) 
 \left( \Gamma \left( 1/2+x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
Now as $x \to +\infty$, the part without the $\sin$ goes to $0$.  But there are many vales of $x$ where the sine in the denominator is zero.  Along a sequence of $x$ where the sine is bounded away from zero, this expression will go to $0$.  For example, $x$ follows the sequence even integers.

So
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty\\ n \in \mathbb N}{\frac {\Gamma \left( 1/2-n \right) \Gamma \left( 1+n \right) }{
\Gamma \left( 1/2+n \right) \Gamma \left( n \right) }} = 0
$$